# Value Error: The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (5,) + inhomogeneous part

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, recommendation-engine

I am getting the error mentioned in the title.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from sklearn.metrics import euclidean_distances
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
import difflib

number_cols = ['valence', 'year', 'acousticness', 'danceability', 'duration_ms', 'energy', 'explicit','instrumentalness', 'key', 'liveness', 'loudness', 'mode', 'popularity', 'speechiness', 'tempo']


def get_song_data(song, spotify_data):
    
    try:
        song_data = spotify_data[(spotify_data['name'] == song['name']) 
                                & (spotify_data['year'] == song['year'])].iloc[0]
        return song_data
    
    except IndexError:
        return find_song(song['name'], song['year'])
        

def get_mean_vector(song_list, spotify_data):
    
    song_vectors = []
    
    for song in song_list:
        song_data = get_song_data(song, spotify_data)
        if song_data is None:
            print('Warning: {} does not exist in Spotify or in database'.format(song['name']))
            continue
        song_vector = song_data[number_cols].values
        song_vectors.append(song_vector)  
    
    song_matrix = np.array(list(song_vectors))
    return np.mean(song_matrix, axis=0)


def flatten_dict_list(dict_list):
    
    flattened_dict = defaultdict()
    for key in dict_list[0].keys():
        flattened_dict[key] = []
    
    for dictionary in dict_list:
        for key, value in dictionary.items():
            flattened_dict[key].append(value)
            
    return flattened_dict


def recommend_songs( song_list, spotify_data, n_songs=10):
    
    metadata_cols = ['name', 'year', 'artists']
    song_dict = flatten_dict_list(song_list)
    
    song_center = get_mean_vector(song_list, spotify_data)
    scaler = song_cluster_pipeline.steps[0][1]
    scaled_data = scaler.transform(spotify_data[number_cols])
    scaled_song_center = scaler.transform(song_center.reshape(1, -1))
    distances = cdist(scaled_song_center, scaled_data, 'cosine')
    index = list(np.argsort(distances)[:, :n_songs][0])
    
    rec_songs = spotify_data.iloc[index]
    rec_songs = rec_songs[~rec_songs['name'].isin(song_dict['name'])]
    return rec_songs[metadata_cols].to_dict(orient='records')
```

However when I run this I get the error;

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[18], line 1
1 recommend_songs([{'name': 'Come As You Are', 'year':1991},
2                 {'name': 'Smells Like Teen Spirit', 'year': 1991},
3                 {'name': 'Lithium', 'year': 1992},
4                 {'name': 'All Apologies', 'year': 1993},
5                 {'name': 'Stay Away', 'year': 1993}],  data)
 
Cell In[17], line 55, in recommend_songs(song_list, spotify_data, n_songs)
52 metadata_cols = ['name', 'year', 'artists']
53 song_dict = flatten_dict_list(song_list)
55 song_center = get_mean_vector(song_list, spotify_data)
56 scaler = song_cluster_pipeline.steps[0][1]
57 scaled_data = scaler.transform(spotify_data[number_cols])

Cell In[17], line 33, in get_mean_vector(song_list, spotify_data)
30     song_vector = song_data[number_cols].values
31     song_vectors.append(song_vector)  
33 song_matrix = np.array(list(song_vectors))
34 return np.mean(song_matrix, axis=0)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (5,) + inhomogeneous part.
```

I read somewhere to downgrade numpy version, however I am unable to do so.
I have;

- python 3.11.4
- numpy version is 1.25.2
- pip version is 21.2.4

Comment: Check the types of all values inside song_vector, as lists allow the grouping of different types like numbers, strings or floats, numpy arrays don't allow that and they require the data to have same type. Another approach is to read about numpy object dtype.

Comment: you are trying to make an array from a list of items that differ in size.

Comment: earlier numpy versions would have complained about 'ragged' array or needing to be object dtype.  You need to examine your data.  How much of this code is your own, or at least something you understand?

Comment: You need to examine `song_vectors`, the list that you are trying to make into an array.